# Using Hawtio to start route stops Camel message body knowing its class

Tags: apache-camel, hawtio

I am using Hawtio with Camel version 2.17.1 to control routes within the camel context.
When I stop and then restart one of my routes with Hawtio I encounter an unusual
issue with the message being seemingly unaware of its class.

The messages are read from a queue and all start as Strings. These are
then unmarshalled successfully using an xsd schema. During the choice, the body is 
always found to be an unknown type despite being unmarshalled to the correct 
class prior to this. Confusingly, the approriate custom type converter is then used
to convert the message to the expected type.

```
<route id="responseRoute" autoStartup="false">
    <from uri="{{response.from.uri}} />
    <transacted ref="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED_CONSUMER"/>

    // class is String

    <unmarshal ref="unmarshalJAXB" />

    // class is type.A

    <choice>
        <when>
            <simple>${body} is 'type.A'</simple>
            <log message="Body is type A" />
            <convertBodyTo type="type.C" />
        </when>
        <when>
            <simple>${body} is 'type.B'</simple>
            <log message="Body is type B" />
            <convertBodyTo type="type.C" />
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            // always this option - unknown type
            <log message="Body is unknown type" />
            <convertBodyTo type="type.C" />
        </otherwise>
    </choice>

    <marshal ref="marshalJAXB" />

    <to uri="{{response.to.uri}}" />
</route>
```

If the autoStartup option is set to true, then every message processes successfully,
hitting the correct option in the choice block.

Why does starting the route with Hawtio stop the message body knowing what class it is?
Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Could you provide the error dump?

Comment: Unfortunately there are no errors.